# Installing gems inside the project folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

Is there a way to install gems via `bundle install` so they won't install in the ruby folder but in the project's folder? (and I'll use .gitignore on it)

Is there a way of doing this for only some of the gems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the installation path with `--path`:

```
bundle install --path='./gems/'
```

This is a remembered option, so you only need to specify it the first time.